camel batch processing intermittent poll failures with NullPointerException
We are using camel kafka to read message in a batch and process them , intermittently we are seeing poll failures and resulted in messages getting lost.
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.util.List.add(Object)" because "this.exchangeList" is null
    at org.apache.camel.component.kafka.consumer.support.batching.KafkaRecordBatchingProcessor.processExchange(KafkaRecordBatchingProcessor.java:137)
    at org.apache.camel.component.kafka.consumer.support.batching.KafkaRecordBatchingProcessorFacade.processPolledRecords(KafkaRecordBatchingProcessorFacade.java:59)
    at org.apache.camel.component.kafka.KafkaFetchRecords.startPolling(KafkaFetchRecords.java:353)

Same issue for camel 4.4.0 & camel 4.6.0.

This is fixed in camel 4.4.3 and 4.7.0 https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-20790

initialization Issue
The exchangeList field might not be properly initialized before it's being used in the processExchange method. Ensure that it's initialized correctly, possibly in a constructor or an initialization method.

thats with in camel library
